# Using a HttpServlet Session Attribute in JSF

Tags: jsf, session, servlets, jpa, ejb

How can I use a session attribute in my JSF (such attribute is obtained through a 3rd party HttpServlet as below), so I can display it to the user and store it along with the other values in the form?

The HttpServlet (objects obtained remotely through a 3rd party Login Resource):

```
public class ServletLogar extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String req = request.getParameter("pag");

    IntranetAuth intranetAuth = new IntranetAuth();
    if (!intranetAuth.isAuth(request, response)) {
        response.sendRedirect(intranetAuth.urlLoginPage);
        return;
    }

    UserVO userVO = intranetAuth.usuerVO;

    if (intranetAuth.isAuth(request, response, req, req) {
        BeanLogin beanLogin = new BeanLogin(); // a POJO
        beanLogin.setxUserID(userVO.getUserID());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("xUserID", userVO.getUserID());
        response.sendRedirect(req);
    }

   //doGet and doPost ommited
}
```

The JSF (form):

```
<!-- [...] -->
<h:form id="ViagensCreateForm">
 <h:panelGroup id="display">
  <p:panelGrid columns="2">

   <p:outputLabel value="Type the Reason:" for="reason" />
   <p:inputText id="reason" value="#{viagensController.selected.reason}" />

   <p:outputLabel value="UserID (the sessionAttribute):" for="userID" />
   <p:inputText id="userID" value="#{SessionScope.userID}" title="userID" />

  </p:panelGrid>
 <p:commandButton actionListener="#{viagensController.saveNew}" value="Save" />
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The ViagensController:

```
@Named(value = "viagensController")
@ViewScoped
public class ViagensController extends AbstractController<Viagens> implements Serializable {//generics:passing JPA Entity class, where the 'reason' in JSF is defined
public ViagensController() {
    super(Viagens.class);
 }
}
```

The AbstractController (for the **selected** in JSF above and other methods):

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> {

@Inject
private AbstractFacade<T> ejbFacade;
private Class<T> itemClass;
private T selected;
private Collection<T> items;

private enum PersistAction {
    CREATE,
    DELETE,
    UPDATE
}

public AbstractController() {
}

public AbstractController(Class<T> itemClass) {
    this.itemClass = itemClass;
}

public T getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

// Pass in the currently selected item
public void setSelected(T selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
}

protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
}

public Collection<T> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findAll();
    }
    return items;
}

// Pass in collection of items
public void setItems(Collection<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

// Apply changes to an existing item to the data layer.
public void save(ActionEvent event) {
    String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/viagensBundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Updated");
    persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, msg);
}

// Store a new item in the data layer.
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
    String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/viagensBundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Created");
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, msg);
    if (!isValidationFailed()) {
        items = null; // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}

public void delete(ActionEvent event) {/*implementations ommited*/ }

private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
    if (selected != null) {
        this.setEmbeddableKeys();
        try {
            if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                this.ejbFacade.edit(selected);
            } else {
                this.ejbFacade.remove(selected);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            String msg = "";
            Throwable cause = JsfUtil.getRootCause(ex.getCause());
            if (cause != null) {
                if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                    ConstraintViolationException excp = (ConstraintViolationException) cause;
                    for (ConstraintViolation s : excp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(s.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
                    if (msg.length() > 0) {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
                    } else {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/viagensBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
}

// Creates a new instance of an underlying entity and assigns it to Selected property.
public T prepareCreate(ActionEvent event) {
    T newItem;
    try {
        newItem = itemClass.newInstance();
        this.selected = newItem;
        initializeEmbeddableKey();
        return newItem;
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

// Inform the user interface whether any validation error exist on a page.
public boolean isValidationFailed() {
    return JsfUtil.isValidationFailed();
}

// Retrieve all messages as a String to be displayed on the page.
public String getComponentMessages(String clientComponent, String defaultMessage) {
    return JsfUtil.getComponentMessages(clientComponent, defaultMessage);
}
```

}

The ViagensFacade:

```
@Stateless
public class ViagensFacade extends AbstractFacade<Viagens> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "viagensPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public ViagensFacade() {
    super(Viagens.class);
 }    
}
```

The AbstractFacade:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {{ /*impl. ommited*/ }
public List<T> findAll() {{ /*impl. ommited*/ }
public List<T> findRange(int[] range) { /*impl. ommited*/ }
public int count() { /*impl. ommited*/ }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**update code:**

```
package br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
//import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped; --> Thank you, John Ament !!
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

private bean_login myUser;

public bean_login getMyUser() {
    return myUser;
}

public void setMyUser(bean_login myUser) {
    this.myUser = myUser;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String uid = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("xChave").toString();
    myUser = new bean_login();
    myUser.setxChave(uid);
    System.out.print("from init:" + myUser.toString());
}
}
```

And in my JSF:

```
<p:outputLabel value="UserID (the sessionAttribute):" for="userID" />
<p:inputText id="userID" value="#{userBean.myUser.xChave}" title="userID" />

<p:outputLabel value="Type the Reason:" for="reason" />
<p:inputText id="reason" value="#{viagensController.selected.reason}" />
```

The error:

```
WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'Solicitante', tabela 'DIAGE.hpa.viagens'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.
Error Code: 515
Call: INSERT INTO DIAGE.hpa.viagens (requisicao, DtFim, DtIni, DtReg, Motivo, Ok, Trecho, Missionario, Solicitante, UOR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [10 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.entities.Viagens[ requisicao=777 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4200)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1439)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3166)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy576.edit(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.facades.__EJB31_Generated__ViagensFacade__Intf____Bean__.edit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.facades.ViagensFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.edit(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.AbstractController.persist(AbstractController.java:134)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.AbstractController.saveNew(AbstractController.java:109)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.ViagensController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.saveNew(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

WARNING:   DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'Solicitante', tabela 'DIAGE.hpa.viagens'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.
Error Code: 515
Call: INSERT INTO DIAGE.hpa.viagens (requisicao, DtFim, DtIni, DtReg, Motivo, Ok, Trecho, Missionario, Solicitante, UOR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [10 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.entities.Viagens[ requisicao=777 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)


WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ViagensFacade, method: public void br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.facades.AbstractFacade.edit(java.lang.Object)
WARNING:   javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:725)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy576.edit(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.facades.__EJB31_Generated__ViagensFacade__Intf____Bean__.edit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.facades.ViagensFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.edit(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.AbstractController.persist(AbstractController.java:134)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.AbstractController.saveNew(AbstractController.java:109)
    at br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.beans.ViagensController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.saveNew(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'Solicitante', tabela 'DIAGE.hpa.viagens'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.
Error Code: 515
Call: INSERT INTO DIAGE.hpa.viagens (requisicao, DtFim, DtIni, DtReg, Motivo, Ok, Trecho, Missionario, Solicitante, UOR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [10 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(br.com.bb.upb.diage.viagens.entities.Viagens[ requisicao=777 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    ... 69 more
```

Comment: What j2ee version do you use? Was your UserBean created?

Comment: Hi jjd. So, I guess the UserBean was instantiated, since it was declared via annotations - the newer generic bean management mechanism, which JSR I forgot, is supported by JEE7+Glassfish 4, which I'm using, correct? The full (Netbeans) project is available at https://github.com/f6750699/navApp.git .Thanks.

Comment: If it was declared, it does not mean it was instantiated. Have you debugged it? There are cases when it maight be not the case. For instance CDI is not working.

Comment: I read that a ManagedBean is instantiated on-demand and not before, so if it's never referenced in a displayed View's xhtml, it won't get instantiated. If non-JSF code needs the bean, it must manually construct and initialize it, then place it in the HttpSession object. JSF code will then see it in the HttpSession and will not attempt to re-instantiate it and the JSF and non-JSF code can happily share it subject to the usual thread-safety considerations. So, I think that just by referencing #{userBean.userID} in a view.xhtml will instantiate the MB. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, jjd. As John Ament showed below, the problem was about an import package issue, which was resolved. But now, the problem concerns in storing the user session attribute in database along with other values informed by the user. (please, see the update code above). Your help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert in Portuguese of any kind, but I think the error description is pretty clear - you are trying to insert a null value to the not nullable column. 'Solicitante'. 'Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'Solicitante', tabela 'DIAGE.hpa.viagens'; a coluna não permite nulos.'

Comment: Ok, sorry for that Portuguese issue. But your observation is right: it's not possible to insert a NULL value in the Solicitante (=Informer) column. The problem is: I've already injected the desired session attribute, but how can I pass it along with the other values informed by the user in the same form to be stored in database? Please, see the codes above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalRequest()` which can be type casted to a `HttpServletRequest`.  From there you can get access to the Session.

Comment: John Ament, I've tried this, but no success. Please, see the code update which I've tried and give me a help.

Comment: Hmmm.  So first, the getter for `myUser` is really dangerous.  You're always creating a new instance when it's called.  Use an instance variable and just let post construct do its work.  Can you include the import statements for this new class?

Comment: Hi John Ament. I put the imports in the update code section. I put a Netbeans (called iro) project available for download at: https://github.com/f6750699/navApp.git

Comment: Ah ha.  You need to consistently use either the CDI annotations or the JSF annotations.  Mixing them this way will cause the types of problems you are facing.

Comment: Ok. But what should I do? Do I need to change the packages? The annotations? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` you want `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

Comment: John Ament, you really showed me the right way and the CDI is working fine. Thank you so much! Now, despite the user is being displayed, it's been passed NULL to the EJB layer. How can I pass that user session attribute to be stored in database, along with the other values informed by the user?  (please, see the update code above). Thanks!

Comment: Need more info.  Can you show your action method and the UI code that calls it?

Comment: Ok. Please, see the updated codes AbstractFacade, ViagensFacade, AbstractController and the JSF (form) above. Thanks.

Comment: John Ament, thank you. Since my problem for this question was resolved, I've asked another one. If you can, please, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509029/storing-a-http-session-attribute-in-database